# Custom dialog to alert web page didn't load

Tags: android, dialog, webview, android-alertdialog

I want to alert people if a page doesn't load and the Toast feature doesn't stay up for a long enough period of time (but i left the code in and commented out in case i want to go back to it). So I am now trying to do a custom dialog instead but that doesn't pop up.

I basically open the web page, which works
I added a loader in the status bar so folks will see the page is loading, and that works
I added code to keep the navigation in the app so folks don't exit to a new browser, and that works
As I said, the toast technically works, but doesn't stay up for as long as I would like
Then I added the custom alert dialog, and that's where I fail

I also created a separate XML file for the custom alert

And then I haven't even get this far yet, but would I need to add code to close it, or does just hitting the back button automatically close it?

Thanks!

Here's my code in the .java file

```
    public class FC extends Activity {

    WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //this one line added for progress support
        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

        setContentView(R.layout.web);

        //makes progress bar visible
        getWindow().setFeatureInt( Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);

        //get web view
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById( R.id.webWeb );
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.setInitialScale(45);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.chipmunkmobile.com");

        //sets the Chrome client
        final Activity MyActivity = this;
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
        {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
            {
                //makes the bar disappear after URL is loaded, and changes string to Loading...
                MyActivity.setTitle("Loading...");
                MyActivity.setProgress(progress * 100);

                //return the app name after finish loading
                if(progress == 100)
                    MyActivity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }

        });

        //makes page stay in same web client
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
            }
        });


        //looks to see if connects
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NO CONNECTION?\nVisit the Cyberspots in the SW and NW Halls to find out how to get on the free WiFi", 
                    //Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //showDialog(0);

                AlertDialog.Builder builder;
                AlertDialog alertDialog;

                Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog,
                        (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));

                TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
                text.setText("WHATEVER");
                ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.imgid);
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);

                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                builder.setView(layout);
                alertDialog = builder.create();


            }
        });
    }
```

Here's my code in the .xml file

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:id="@+id/layout_root"
  android:padding="10dp">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" 
        />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using an alert I just used an embedded HTML error message...I didn't find a fix to the `alertDialog` problem

Answer (score 0):

Add an `alertDialog.show()` to the end of the method to actually display the dialog.

Also, you may want to add a `setNeutralButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {...}` and call `finish` to close the dialog in the OnClickListener.

Comment: Thanks for trying but that crashed the program. Any other suggestions??

Comment: how did it crash the program?  could you post the stack trace?